# How to open icloud app (Files) programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, icloud-drive

I want to open iCloud app (file)from my app programmatically.

I am uploading file on iCloud so I want to redirect user to iCloud directory.

It's not necessary to move direct app directory if just open iCloud from app is enough.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to look into [UIDocumentBrowserViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller). You'll need to add a few keys to `Info.plist`.

`UIFileSharingEnabled` goes for `Application supports iTunes file sharing` - `YES`

`LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` : `Supports opening documents in place` - `YES`

or single (iOS 11+)

`UISupportsDocumentBrowser` : `Supports Document Browser` - `YES`

It seems there's no way to `UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "")!)` for Files.

Comment: @hardikvyas it opens "Files browser" where user can navigate wherever he/she wants. iOS 11+ though.